# Yeoman/Angular/Coffee .when() router won't route - cannot GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, router, yeoman

Have a basic install from the Yeoman angular scaffolder and for the life of the, I cannot get the router to load a basic template. Here's my setup

```
//  index.html
<body ng-app="mvmdApp">
  <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>//  not sure how ng-view plays into this
```

```
//  app.coffee
myAppModule = angular.module("mvmdApp", [])
  .config( ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
    $locationProvider.html5Mode true

    $routeProvider
      .when("/",
        templateUrl: "views/main.html"
        controller: "MainCtrl"
      )
      .when("/youtube",
        templateUrl: "views/youtube.html"
        controller: "YoutubeCtrl"
      )
  )
```

```
//  main.js
angular.module('mvmdApp')
  .controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.awesomeThingss = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate'
      'AngularJS'
      'Karma'
    ]

    $scope.youtube = ( $scope ) ->
      alert 'hi'

  .controller "YoutubeCtrl", ( $scope ) ->
    alert 'Work!'
```

```
//  views/youtube.html
<div class="youtube-unit">
  <div class="outer-frame">
    <div class="inner-frame">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/2FNEiTjcMM0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the main controller loads fine, I tried as much as possible to duplicate it

Going to localhost:9000/youtube gives me a `Cannot GET /youtube` message. I feel like I've tried every combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5 mode is not only about Javascript, it also needs the server to support it.

When you try /youtube it first goes to the server, if the server can't manage it, you should render the angular application so the router can catch the route and show what you need.

I am not sure if Yeoman supports html5 mode to be honest.

You could try [linemanjs](http://linemanjs.com) which is like Yeoman and it supports html5 mode.

If you want to use Yeoman, google for html5 mode for yeoman or use hashbang :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not straightforward, but you CAN install the `connect-modrewrite` middleware and all you have to do is rewrite any path to `index.html`. You also have to edit `GruntFile.js` to fix live reload, and do the rewrite on your production server as well. See here for some pointers on how to go about doing this - http://ericduran.io/2013/05/31/angular-html5Mode-with-yeoman/